# Apache Camel: RabbitMQ polling consumer and acknowledgement mode

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel, amqp

I am trying to handle exception in a simple scenario with RabbitMQ polling consumer. A route is very simple:

```
<route id="consume">
  <from uri="timer:consume?period=600000" />
  <log message=">>>Consumer start"/>
  <pollEnrich>
    <constant>spring-rabbitmq:ex1?queues=bar&amp;prefetchCount=1</constant>
  </pollEnrich>
  <throwException exceptionType="java.lang.NullPointerException"
    message="Not supported, sorjan"/>
  <log message=">>>Body:  ${body}"/>
  <log message=">>>Headers:  ${headers}"/>
</route>
```

I wonder if it is possible to somehow manage acknowledgments like it happens in a simple consumer? I would expect a message is not delivered and stayed in a queue in case of exception - is it possible to get this behavior?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem right.
I don't see how you are handling exceptions.
As far as I understand, your route is executed every 10 minutes. Then an exchange with empty body is enriched. Afterwards a NullpointerException is thrown.

Comment: Hi Rainer and thanks for your reply. I am not trying to handle an exception. If I start the route with this: <from uri="spring-rabbitmq:ex1?queues=bar&amp;prefetchCount=1" /> and after it just throw exception - then messages from the queue will not be marked as delivered and stayed in the queue until redelivery attempts are reached. With pollEnrich messages are removed from the queue immediately and if exception is thrown later on messages will be just lost.